# Calling function in truffle console error

Tags: ethereum, truffle

How do I correctly call a function of a contract that in the truffle console?

Using the petshop example project, I migrated the contract onto the network successfully.

In the truffle console I executed:

```
var ad = Adoption.deployed()
```

This yields the reply:

```
undefined
```

When I execute `ad.adopt(23)`; adopt being the function name and 23 being the unit parameter; I get the exception `TypeError: ad.getAdopters is not a function`

What was my mistake in calling the function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside Truffle console

```
ContractName.deployed().then(function(instance){app = instance})
app.adopt(23)//call method on contract class
```

Try this inside your app.

```
//from App.js
App.contracts.SmartContractName.deployed().then(function(instance){
   return instance.adopt(23)//call method on contract class
}).then(function(){

}).catch(function(err){
   console.log(err);
})
```